# Delaying a method chain using Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a service object that has `#call` to execute an expensive operation. I would like to use Sidekiq to execute this operation.

I am using sidekiq and [sidekiq-delay](https://github.com/dlibanori/sidekiq-delay). 
The following gives me an error:

`MyService.sidekiq_delay.new(arg).call`

because when I call `.sidekiq_delay` and chain another method, it returns a string. How can I delay both the instantiation and `#call` on `MyService` using Sidekiq, without having to create another worker?

**Edit**

`MyService.sidekiq_delay.new(arg).call` gives me the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for "06139e957f4e73a7a84d9290":String
```

`MyService.new(arg).sidekiq_delay.call` give me the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sidekiq_delay' for #<MyService:0x007fa81d250a40>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate and then delay it.

```
MyService.new(arg).delay.call
```

**EDIT:**

`MyService.new(arg)` should respond to `find(id)` method. If it don't, you need to write [Custom Workers](http://github.com/dlibanori/sidekiq-delay#custom-works)

Comment: Is there a way to delay a method chain without having to create another worker? (I've edited the question) Thanks.

Comment: I am using both DelayedJob and Sidekiq in my app, and calling `.delay` will use DelayedJob. I have configured the app to use `.sidekiq_delay` instead. 
However, `.sidekiq_delay` does not work when I do `MyService.new(arg).sidekiq_delay.call` Any suggestions?

Comment: Post more related code in your ques. I am not aware what `sidekiq_delay` trying to do and what is the definition of it

Comment: To work with  `MyService.new(arg).sidekiq_delay.call`, `MyService.new(arg)` should respond to `find(id)` method. If it don't, you need to use Custom Workers: https://github.com/dlibanori/sidekiq-delay#custom-works